# Conserving "the"

Tags: word-usage

I like to conserve "the" in a sentence. I sent an email describing the location of certain keys and this is the best I could do

> I left **the** keys at **the** shelf next to **the** phone in **the** kitchen

Can this be rephrased to reduce the number of "the"? Also, the recipient knows the keys are at his house, could I avoid using "the kitchen"?

Comment: Your preference doesn't seem sensible to me. Do you have any better explanation of why you like to "conserve 'the' in a sentence"? People are not going to get sick of seeing the word "the". A "cure" seems likely to be worse than the "disease".

Comment: 'Conserve' does not mean 'reduce', so your usage of 'conserve' is unclear. I've ignored it in my answer, focusing instead on which definite noun phrases are necessary in your sentence.

Answer (score 2):

One "the" can be omitted without omitting any other semantic content by using kitchen as a descriptor of the phone:

> I left the keys on the shelf next to the kitchen phone.

If the speaker and listener are assumed to commonly understand "kitchen phone shelf" to be the shelf in question, you could say:

> I left the keys on the kitchen phone shelf.

Otherwise, to remove the second "the" you would need to omit "shelf" entirely.

To remove the first "the" you'd have to be speaking very informally at which point grammatical rules don't apply but semantics is still in play:

> Left keys by the kitchen phone, seeya after work hun.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence *I left the keys on the shelf next to the phone in the kitchen* is fine. English speakers aren't likely to notice four *thes* in everyday usage because they're natural; and we're not normally processing the individual *thes* but four noun phrases. I've changed *at the shelf* to *on the shelf* as it is more idiomatic.

You can omit *the kitchen* if this noun phrase is not vital to helping the person you're taking to identify *which keys* you're talking about. So, yes, if the listener knows your talking about his house then you can omit *the kitchen* (assuming there are no other keys on shelves next to phones in another room in the same house).

A speaker might be more likely to omit *on the  shelf* if there's only one phone in the kitchen. If there are two phones in the house, then keeping *the kitchen* seems required, unless you've already established that you're talking about a different room.

In short, you need to give only enough information for the person you're talking to to be able to identify which keys you're talking about. The following might be enough information: *I left the keys in the kitchen*, especially if they are easy to see or if *on the shelf next to the phone* is a known or easily guessed location for placing keys.

Answer (score -1):

There is a shelf next to the kitchen phone, and the keys are on it.